# Assign int value to vector using iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm sitting on a small exercise in C++ Primer (3.23) for almost 2 days. I've tried many ways of assigning a value to `vector<int>`. I'll give you an actual exercise on which I work and code with which I came so far, but its totally wrong. I did a lot of research but found nothing useful.

Write a program to create a `vector` with 10 `int` elements. Using an iterator, assign each element a value that is twice its current value. Test the program by printing `vector`

And this is my code

```
int main(){  
vector<int> num(10);

for (auto it=num.begin();it != num.end() ;++it)//iterating through each element in vector 
{
    *it=2;//assign value to vector using iterator
    for (auto n=num.begin() ;n!=num.end();++n)//Iterating through existing elements in vector 
    {   
        *it+=*n;// Compound of elements from the first loop and 2 loop iteration
    }    
    cout<<*it<<" ";
}

keep_window_open("~");
return 0;
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to assign an `int` value to each `vector` element using an iterator (I did to 1 but not to the five elements)! In addition I was breaking my head on how to do this exercise with 10 elements in `vector`, to each element must be a different value and an iterator must do the assignment.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main(){  

    vector<int> num(10);

    int initial_value = 2;
    *num.begin() = initial_value;
    cout<<*num.begin()<<" ";
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator it=num.begin()+1; it != num.end() ;++it)//iterating thru each elementn in vector 
    {
        *it=*(it-1) * 2;//assign value wtih 2 times of previous iterator

        cout<<*it<<" ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You just need to give some initial value to the first iterator and the rest is calculated in a for loop

Comment: Excellent ! Thank you !  I did same loop before but didnt use `*it=*(it-1) * 2;`

Answer (score 10):

Here's a much cleaner version of the accepted answer, using the concept of incrementing the iterator instead of a for loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{  
    vector<int> num(10);

    int n = 1;
    vector<int>::iterator it = num.begin();
    vector<int>::iterator itEnd = num.end();

    while (it != itEnd)
    {
        *it = n = n*2;
        cout << *it << " ";
        it++;
    }
}
```

Comment: plus 1 for your assignment.